# Why is parameterized constructor called, when we assign an integer value to an object of a class?

Tags: c++, constructor, assignment-operator

The code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Integer
{
    int num;

    public:
        Integer()
        {
            num = 0;
            cout<<"1";
        }
        
        Integer(int arg)
        {
            cout<<"2";
            num = arg;
        }
        int getValue()
        {
            cout<<"3";
            return num;
        }

};

int main()
{
    Integer i;
    i = 10;  // calls parameterized constructor why??
    cout<<i.getValue();
    return 0;

}
```

In the above code, the statement `i=10` calls the parameterized constructor. Can you please explain this.

Comment: It uses the compiler provided assignment operator (which takes a const Integer&) to do that it needs to construct a new Integer through Integer(int).

Comment: What do you expect should happen instead? An error? (It's a genuine question, an answer should address the expectations).

Comment: `10` is a temporary object that is used to initialize `i`. What you have now is `i = Integer(10)` since you are missing assignment operator inside your class.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica  Yes, I was expecting an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parameterized constructor is a converting constructor. C++ is all too happy to make an expression valid, so long as it can find a reasonable conversion sequence to make things work. So as already noted, `10` is converted to an `Integer` temporary, which then gets assigned by the compiler generated `operator= (Integer const&)`.

If you wish to prevent the constructor from being used in unexpected conversions, you can mark it as `explicit`.

```
explicit Integer(int arg) { /* ... */}
```

It then stops being a converting constructor, and the assignment will not be possible without a cast (or custom assignment operator, provided by you).

Comment: Which is the main reason why you should declare *all* constructors with one parameter as *explicit*.

Answer (score 3):

Parameterized ctor is being called because temporary `Integer` object is created and then assigned to your `i` object like:

```cpp
i = Integer(10);
```

If you specify assignment operator like:

```cpp
Integer& operator=(int const val) {
    num = val;
    return *this;
}
```

parameterized ctor won't be called.